# Multiplicación en HTML y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando unos trabajos en HTML y JavaScript. Tengo un problema en mi script de multiplicación de matriz 3x3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mu(){
        document.getElementById("nuevamatriz").innerHTML= ("<h4> RESULTADO DE MULTIPLICACION </h4>");
            for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
                for (j=1;j<=3;j++){
                    var suma = parseInt(document.getElementById('a'+i+j).value) * parseInt(document.getElementById('b'+j+i).value);
                    var c = c + suma;
                    if(j== 1){
                        document.getElementById('c'+i+j).innerHTML= c;
                    }
                    else if(j ==2){
                        document.getElementById('c'+i+j).innerHTML= c;
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById('c'+i+j).innerHTML= c;
                        }
                }

            }               

        return false;   
    }
</script>
```

Esto muestra lo siguiente

```
RESULTADO DE MULTIPLICACION

NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN
```

Se que existen muchas forma de hacer la multiplicación de matrices y quiero hacer este ejercicio a través  document.getElementById().value

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el html correspondiente?

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de mirar como convertir `string` a numero. Y que `NaN` significa "not a number" (no es un numero)  Por ejemplo con `Number()`. Un saludo

Comment: Intenta cambiando  `var c = c + suma` por  `var c =  suma;` y dinos el resultado.  Si se ejecuta en `var c = c + 1` da como resultado `NaN`. Quizas sea eso ya que reproductir el error es imposible.

Comment: Cambie var c = c + suma por var c = suma; y ahora me tira resultados

Comment: te funciono la solucion?

Answer (score 2):

Es por que estas declarando `c` dentro de tu for, cuando creas la variable `c` tiene un valor de `null` y le quieres asigna el mismo valor de c (que es null) mas un núumero y ahí da el error

```
var c = c + suma;
```

```js
console.log("Con error");
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
   //Creas c, pero c no tiene ningun valor (null)
   //Intentas sumar c (null) a un numero y te da el error de NaN
   var c = c + i;
   console.log(c);
}

console.log("Sin error error");
//Creas primero la variable y le asignas un cero para que sea numérica
var otraSuma = 0; 
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
    otraSuma = otraSuma + i;
   console.log(otraSuma);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en la siguiente expresion:

```
 var c = c + suma;
```

Cambiala por:

```
  var c = suma;
```

En tu codigo estas creando una variable `c` que sera igual a la suma de ella misma con la variable `suma` pero `c` todavia no esta definida.

Si descomponemos la expresion seria asi:

```
var variableTemporal = c + suma;
var c = variableTemporal;
```

Si te fijas, en la primera linea `c` no esta definida sino ya en la segunda linea es cuando se define. Entonces esa expresion se puede definir asi:

```
var variableTemporal = undefined + suma;
var c = variableTemporal;
```

Por lo que `undefined + suma = NaN;`